# overriding parent contentEditable with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some div like this:

```
<div id="op" contentEditable="true">hello<div class="dynamic">......sth
</div> <div class="dynamic"> ...sth
</div> .......<div class="dynamic"> </div>.. <div class="dynamic"> </div>..</div>
```

The divs inside the div with id "op" is created dynamically and appended to "op" with appendChild method. After all the dynamic divs are added, I need to change contentEditable of div "op" to false while  divs inside of "op" to true. Basically, that being said, my target is to be able modify divs with true contentEditable but which are appended to the div with false contentEditable.I did this:

```
document.getElementById("op").setAttribute("contentEditable",false);
document.getElementsByClassName("dynamic").setAttribute("contentEditable",true);
```

This does not work and I think the reason is simple. Although I modified the contentEditable of "dynamic" class divs, they are still inside div which has  false contentEditable.

Is there any way to override the parent contentEditable property such that it allows its child to retain its own contentEditable whenever it has one and applies parent content Editable otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you setting the contentEditable attribute to `false` or `true` for the divs with class "dynamic"? In your snippet you're setting all of the divs to `false`.

The default value for [contentEditable](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#contenteditable) (when it is missing) is `inherit`. So when you set an element's contentEditable to `true`, all children of that element will also be content editable.

Given the following HTML you can edit all of the text and even accidentally remove the child `div`:

```
<div id="parent" contenteditable="true">
    Parent div
    <div id="child"><!-- contentEditable="true" is implied -->
        Child div
    </div>
</div>
```

And with this HTML you can only edit the text "Parent div":

```
<div id="parent" contenteditable="true">
    Parent div
    <div id="child" contenteditable="false">
        Child div
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: My case is "parent" is false and "child" is true as opposite to what you showed in the last snippet. But that resulted into whole div as false content editable.